# $p$-norm is a convex function of $p$

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

For what measures $\mu$ and what intervals $(a,b) \subset (1,\infty)$ is the function

$$p\mapsto \|f\|_p =\left(\int |f|^p d\mu \right)^{2/p}$$

a convex function of $p$ on $(a,b)$ for all $f\in L^1(\mu) \cap L^\infty(\mu)$? When is it concave?

Comment: Did you mean to put 1/p as the exponent instead of 2/p?

Comment: No, the $2/p$ was intentional

Comment: Then this is not a norm. More importantly: what did you try?